# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() error

Tags: java, php, android

I have a problem in sending data from and Android application to PHP using Restful Web services. I am getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()" error. Please advice me on what to do. Thanks.

This is the MainActivity.java class

```
package com.example.contactexchange;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText lastnameBox, firstnameBox, phonenoBox, addressBox;
Spinner salutationBox;
ImageView imageview;
Button addPhone, saveBox;
String lastname, firstname, phoneno, address, salutation;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
GetIPAddress getIPaddress = new GetIPAddress();
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String save_contact;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save_contact = getIPaddress.getIP()+"register.php";

    lastnameBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastnameBox);
    firstnameBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnameBox);
    phonenoBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenoBox);
    addressBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressBox);
    salutationBox = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    addPhone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    saveBox = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBox);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.salutation, R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    salutationBox.setAdapter(adapter);

    salutationBox.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         salutation = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

           }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});

    saveBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /*lastname = lastnameBox.getText().toString();
            firstname = firstnameBox.getText().toString();
            phoneno = phonenoBox.getText().toString();
            address = addressBox.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), salutation+" "+lastname+" "+firstname+" "+phoneno+" "+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        */
        new SaveContact().execute();    
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



class SaveContact extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 /**
* Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
* */
boolean failure = false;

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
//   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
 //  pDialog.setMessage("Saving Contact...");
  // pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
 //  pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Check for success tag
   int success;

   lastname = lastnameBox.getText().toString();
   firstname = firstnameBox.getText().toString();
   phoneno = phonenoBox.getText().toString();
   address = addressBox.getText().toString();

   // Building Parameters
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salutation", salutation));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneno", phoneno)); 
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address)); 

    // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(save_contact, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Datae" ,salutation+ " " + firstname+" "+lastname+" "+phoneno+" "+address);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag

        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sussess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the register.php

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['salutation']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) &&    isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['phoneno']) &&      isset($_POST['address'])) {

$salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_info(salutation, first_name, last_name, phone_no, address) VALUES('$salutation', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$phoneno', '$address')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the logcat error

```
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.example.contactexchange.MainActivity$SaveContact.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:147)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.example.contactexchange.MainActivity$SaveContact.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-27 15:16:44.125: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  ... 4 more
07-27 15:16:44.295: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(455): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-27 15:16:46.645: E/InputQueue-JNI(455): channel '40fefa40 PopupWindow:408fcb78 (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

Please advice me on what to do. Thanks

Comment: What is line number `MainActivity.java:147` ?

Comment: you can not use toast in `doInBackground method`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your issue is with the EditTexts you're reading inside on doInBackground:

```
EditText lastnameBox, firstnameBox, phonenoBox, addressBox;
```

I would suggest you to get the values of these editText fields on button click listener, save these values as Strings and send these values as params to the doInBackground.

Your doInBackground is already ready to accept an array of String so you just need to get them as args values.